# HTML/CSS sidebar and tile view

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I would like to restructure a page on my angularJS website. Currently data is being displayed in a table view; I would like to create a left sidebar with a (tile) list of names. When a name is clicked on, the right sidebar should display additional details about the selected individual. Any guidance on how to efficiently accomplish this using HTML and CSS will be much appreciated.

Here is the simple code I have so far:

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.lft_sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 120px 120px 120px;
  grid-template-areas: "....... header header" "sidebar content content" "footer  footer  footer";
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.header,
.footer {
  background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">Header</div>

  <div class="lft_sidebar">Neme 1</div>
  <div class="lft_sidebar">Name 2</div>
  <div class="lft_sidebar">Name 3</div>
  <div class="lft_sidebar">Name 4</div>

  <div class="rght_sidebar"> More details about Selected Name</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You haven't stated what problem(s) you're having, or what help you need; you may want to re-read the "*[ask]*" guidance. Either way, though, please [edit] your question to clearly explain your expected end result, and the problems you're having.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `grid-column-start` and `grid-column-end` CSS properties to specify where a grid cell should start / end.

```css
body {
margin: 40px;
}

.lft_sidebar {
    grid-area: sidebar;
}

.left {
   grid-column-start: 1;
   grid-column-end: 2;
}

.rght_sidebar {
   grid-column-start: 2;
   grid-column-end: 4;
}

.header {
   grid-column-start: 1;
   grid-column-end: 4;
}

.wrapper {
    display: grid;
grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
   
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #444;
}


.box {
 background-color: #444;
 color: #fff;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 10px;
 font-size: 150%;
}

.header,
.footer {
background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="header">Header</div>


<div class="left">
  <div class="lft_sidebar">Neme 1</div>
  <div class="lft_sidebar">Name 2</div>
  <div class="lft_sidebar">Name 3</div>
  <div class="lft_sidebar">Name 4</div>
</div>

<div class="rght_sidebar"> More details about Selected Name</div>


</div>
```